# Fixed action bar display in footer of phonegap blackberry 10

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am developing phonegap blackberry app using webworks.

Is there any way to fix action bar in footer of the blackberry 10 mobile using phonegap??

Iscroll has an issue in blackberry.so i am expecting some other answer

Answer (score 0):

Right now your best bet is to use our bbUI.js framework to achieve the BB10 'look and feel'. You'll get this kind of UI right out-of-the-box.

On a side note, you do not need to use iScroll on BB10 at all. We use hardware accelerated scrolling which performs way better.

Here's a couple links to get you headed in right direction:

bbUI.js - https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js
More info on scrolling - http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/01/overflow-scrolling-hardware-acceleration/

Hope that helps

Comment: I have checked this.its not displaying anything in BB10 simulator.so help me out